# Find intersection points for vector construct

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, vector

So in my software I have two vectors. The first vector `matrix` stores the information of the shape of a given 3D model. So I got a vector of arrays to store the x,y,z coordinates of points.

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> matrix;
```

This vector is already sorted, so that I get the contour of the model.
In the second vector `boundingbox` I store the information of a bounding box.

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> boundingbox;
```

In this vector the first four elements describe the bounding box around the contour. To fill the outline I have placed a grid on it. The grid is in this case defined by the software based on a variable. The variable `infill` is set by the user at run-time. So currently my program creats the following image.

[image: Contour with BoundingBox and Infill]

Now the next step would be to find the intersection points between the grid and the contour. My approach to this would be a typical mathematical approach.
I would use two `for`-loops. The first loop would be used to iterate over the grid so that each line of the grid is called once.

The second loop would be used the vector to undergo matrix. I developed a pseudo code, in which I describe my procedure.

```
int fillingStart; //first element of boundingbox to contain information about the grid
int n; //number of lines in the Grid. 
for(size_t i=fillingStart; i<(n-1); i+2)
{
  double A_x=boundingbox[j][0];
  double A_y=boundingbox[j][1];
  double B_x=boundingbox[j+1][0];
  double B_y=boundingbox[j+1][0];

  double AB_x=B_x-A_x;
  double AB_y=B_y-A_y;

  double intersectionpoint_y = DBL_MAX;
  double intersectionpoint_x = DBL_MAX;
  double intersectionpoint2_y = DBL_MAX;
  double intersectionpoint2_x = DBL_MAX;

  for(size_t j=0; j<(matrix.size()-1); j++)
  {
     double C_x = matrix[j][0];
     double C_y = matrix[j][1];
     double D_x = matrix[j+1][0];
     double D_y = matrix[j+1][1];

     double CD_x = D_x-C_x;
     double CD_y = D_y-C_y;

     double s = (((C_x-A_x)*(-CD_y))-((-CD_x)*(C_y-A_y)))/((AB_x*(-CD_y))-((-CD_x)*AB_y));//Cramer's rule
     double t = ((AB_x*(C_y-A_y))-((C_x-A_x)*AB_y)) / ((AB_x * (-CD_y))-((-CD_x)*AB_y));//Cramer's rule

     double point_x = A_x+s*AB_x;
     double point_y = A_y*s*AB_y;

    if(point_x < intersectionpoint_x && point_y < intersectionpoint_y)
    {
        intersectionpoint_x = point_x;
        intersectionpoint_y = point_y;
    }
    else if(point_x < intersectionpoint2_x && point_y < intersectionpoint2_y)
    {
        intersectionpoint2_x = point_x;
        intersectionpoint2_y = point_y;
    }
  }

  intersects.push_back(std::array<double, 3>());
  double q = boundingbox.size()-1;
  intersects[q][0] = intersectionpoint_x;
  intersects[q][1] = intersectionpoint_y;

  intersects.push_back(std::array<double, 3>());
  double q = boundingbox.size()-1;
  intersects[q][0] = intersectionpoint2_x;
  intersects[q][1] = intersectionpoint2_y;
}
```

With this two loops I would find the intersection points for each line of the grid and each vector (between two points) of the contour. Then I would have to find the two intersection points, closest to the grid line and store these points. The special case would be, if there is something in the contoure, like a hole. In this case I would find four points.

**EDIT:** Why I want to use intersection points is shown in the following figures
[image]
Here we have the contour of a rectangle. As you can see there are just a few points to describe the figure.
The next image shows the filling of the model
[image]
Because of the few points of the contour I have to calculate the intersection points of the contour and the grid.

**EDIT2**: I now got the code working and updated the code here, but the problem is that it saves always the same point in `intersectionpoint`. Thats because of the if-statement, but I cant figure out how get it working.

Comment: How do you *sort* your matrix of 3D points?

Comment: I start with the first element in the vector, calculate the distance to all other points and find the nearest point. Than I swap the second element of the vector with the found element and start the whole procedure for the second element.

Comment: The grid is always like the one in my image. Just to get it straight for me: You mean I should first look at the x-value of the current grid line. The I would go through the vector `matrix` and search for points with a close x-value. If the value of a current point is closer to the grid, I store the point. If not I would continue. That would give me the closest point, without calculating the intersection point. Is this correct?

Comment: But how would I do this for two or more intersection points? If I store the two nearest points, how can I be sure that the found points are over and not next to each other?

Comment: After your edit, I think I misunderstood your question. I though you wanted to find point which were in `matrix`, not point on lines connecting `matrix`'s points.

Comment: I want to calculate the intersection points between points of `matrix` and points of the grid

Comment: @user3794592: You can continue in the way which you described. If there is hole inside the 3D model then this case can be handled as follow: Start going through the grid line from top and go downwards and stop at point of intersection. Now for the same grid line start from below and go upwards and stop at point of intersection. Hope I understood it correctly.

Comment: I am proposing a solution which iterate over each pair of consecutive points in your contour (since it is sorted) and check if there is a line between two points - If there is one, it then computes the intersection (assuming a straight line between the two points). Feel free to comment on my answer if you don't get it.

Comment: @sameerkn :Thanks for the tip. But my biggest problem currently are the lines `double s = ((A_x*(-1))+C_x+CD_x*t)/AB_x;` and `double t = (A_x+AB_x*s-C_x)/CD_x;`. How can I calculate these parameters. To calculate `s` I need to know `t` and to calculate `t` I have to know `s`. One option could be to guess one of these parameters, but that is mathematical incorrect.

Comment: @sameerkn : I now edited my code. My main problem now is to save the intersection points correct. Could you give me a hint, how I could do this?

Comment: @user3794592: In `double A_x=boundingbox[j][0];`  I think it should be `boundingbox[i][0]` instead of `boundingbox[j][0]`. As far as saving of points to file `fp` are concerned then as per your code you may use this method: Element of `vector intersects` are array of size 3, so create `struct XYZ{int x, y, z;}`. `size=intersects.size();fwrite(&size, sizeof(size),1,fp); for(i=0;i<size;++i){struct XYZ st;st.x=intersects[i][0];st.y=intersects[i][1];st.z=intersects[i][2];fwrite(&st, sizeof(st),1,fp);}`

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the contour, and for each two consecutive points, check if there is a line between, and if there is one, compute the intersection point.

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> intersects;

auto it = matrix.begin();

while (it != matrix.end() - 1) {
    auto &p1 = *it;
    auto &p2 = *(++it);
    double x;
    // Check if there is a vertical line between p1 and p2
    if (has_vertical_line(p1, p2, &x)) {
        // The equation of the line joining p1 and p2 is:
        //     (p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]) * x + p1[0]
        double y = (p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]) * x + p1[0];
        intersects.push_back({x, y, 0.0});
    }
}
```

Where `has_vertical_line` is something like:

```
bool has_vertical_line (std::array<double, 3> const& p1, 
                        std::array<double, 3> const& p2,
                        double *px) {
    double x1 = p1[0], x2 = p2[0];
    if (x2 <= x1) {
        std::swap(x1, x2);
    }
    size_t lx2 = closest_from_below(x2),
           lx1 = closest_from_above(x1);
    if (lx1 == lx2) {
        *px = lines[lx1]; // Assuming abscissa
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Where `closest_from_below` and `closest_from_above` are simple function that find the line just below / above the current abscissa (trivial since your lines are vertical).